# Detect task is finished

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, tasks

Is there a way to detect when a task is finished with js, for example I have a task running I can see the progress bar in the top right corner I would like to attach an event so when the task is done to do some js. Is that possible at this stage of craft. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my plugins I inject a little bit of javascript that polls `Craft.cp.runningTaskInfo` for changes to detect if a task is finished.