# How to notify the user from a Task

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, tasks, plugin-pushnotifications

Is it possible to somehow notify the user from a completing task?
I am walking trough a set of .csv files and on completion i would like to notify the user.

```
// last step
$stepIndex = $step + 1;
if ( $stepIndex == $this->getTotalSteps() )
{
    craft()->userSession->getFlash('notice', 'Reroutes  imported.');
    // craft()->userSession->setNotice(Craft::t('Reroutes   imported.'));
    // craft()->userSession->getFlashes();
}

return true;
```

I tried with the `UserSessionService` but i guess that won't work because the task is running separately from the session. If so reloading the page would be a good alternative but how can I let the front-end know of the task being completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way to do this would be to log a message to your Plugin's custom log using

`ExamplePlugin::log( 'TaskName has completed' );`

This would require the user to visit the log and refresh to see if the task had completed - not ideal!

However, if you wanted something that updated as the task was being run you could possibly redirect them to a Plugin template with a text area that  displays a log for the task where you could show completion of each step of the task and then finally a "Completed Task" message.

```
// Create task
$task = craft()->tasks->createTask( 'TaskName', 'desc' ), array(
  'products' => $products
));

// Set session notice for start
craft()->userSession->setNotice(Craft::t('Import process started.'));

// Redirect to Plugin template page that displays a log
$this->redirect( 'templateName?task=' . $task->id );
```

Then inside the task you could log messages to be displayed in that template

```
if($step === $this->getTotalSteps()-1) {
  Log::message( 'Task finished.' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pearce for this insight, maybe in combination what this guy is pointing to http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10158/detect-task-is-finished/10168#10168 it is possible to show this in the current view. For now I will stick with the log options for a first version release.